# Understanding a monitor and software two-way communication through VGA

Tags: windows, display, vga

I have an LG monitor (connected on VGA) that comes with a program called Dual Smart Solution. There's an option on the monitor menu that allows me to enable that program if it's running, and is grayed out if it isn't.

How is that possible and how can I use that trigger from the monitor to run some other software instead?

Comment: Is VGA the only port available? I'm pretty sure that VGA doesn't support sending data or any digital signals. Does your monitor have a DisplayPort or HDMI port?

Answer (score 0):

It's probably using the DDC: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Display_Data_Channel

I doubt that you can use it to trigger other program though. (Well, unless you found out what exact signal the monitor is sending/receiving and write a program for it?)